# Split a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, split, hashmap

I have a HashMap like that:

```
[{cap=1, cop=1, amb=1, tota=1, ull,=1, de=1, ve=1, és=1, d'un=1, va=1, llançat=1, sola.=1, traça,=1, cega.=1, vailet=1, l'altre=1, d'esma=1, camí=1, se=1, un=1, massa=1, i=1, li=1, avançant=1, soca,=1, una=1, roc=1, el=1, buidar-li=1, vaca=1, se'n=1, la=1, en=1, altra=1, l'aigua,=1, topant=1, pel=1}, {abeurar-se=1, com=1, ses=1, no=1, amb=1, tota=1, cingles,=1, pels=1, ferm=1, solia,=1, mes=1, ve=1, és=1, tel:=1, sola.=1, ans=1, cega.=1, d'altres=1, les=1, comes,=1, font=1, a=1, companyes,=1, vegades=1, un=1, ha=1, per=1}]
```

And I would like to split this map in for example 4 parts..

How can I do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by "Splitting a HashMap"? How? What are the rules?

Comment: For example split the hashmap in 4 submaps @Tunaki

Comment: @DavidLopez and how should elements be distributed between the 4 maps? Given that the empty map is a submap of all maps, and a map is a submap of itself, you could just take the original map and 3 empty maps to satisfy these vague requirements.

Comment: We are asking you to define **splitting** a "mapped" data structure. That is the whole key here. You need to specify how to decide which key/value should go into which submap?!

Comment: So what have you tried? Show us your code and where you are stuck.

Comment: The division of the map is to take the hashmap and divide into four equal parts.
For example if I have a dictionary with 40 elements in the first submap I would have to put the first 10 elements of the hashmap, in the second the next 10 ... @AndyTurner

Comment: "first 10 elements" has no particular meaning for a HashMap, it has no guaranteed ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't use `Java 8`, you will need to iterate manually over your main `Map` then filter it to create your sub `Map` like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> mainMap = ...
Map<String, Integer> subMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : mainMap.entrySet()) {
    if (some criteria here) {
        subMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```